# How to apply different SyncDirectionOrder for different columns in one table

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

According to your suggestion I have created 2 scopes and both have different SyncDirectionOrder:

Scope one contains columns

- AddressID,
- AccountID,
- AddressIDpda,
- CreatedOn,
- ModifiedOn,
- MoveToCRM,
- twg_User

and scope 2nd contains columns

- AddressID,
- AccountID,
- Line1,
- Line2,
- Line3,
- Line4,
- ApartmentNumber

and etc..

When I try to sync both at a time I am getting error message *"The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = base,Column name = Line1 ]"*

Answer (score 0):

that will not work. if you just specified SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault for the second scope, it will re-use the insert/update and the UDT of the first scope. so while your select_changes sp will get the changes, the insert and update procedure will expect the columns in the first scope. as previously suggested, set the object prefix and schema property during provisioning